# Android and Ffmpeg. Play video (audio and video syncing WITHOUT USING SDL)

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have build ffmpeg library and made simple project where I decode video stream and show it on SurfaceView. Now I need to play sound stream of my video file. And the biggest problem for me is  synchronization. I saw tutorials but all of them show how to do this using SDL. But for this I need to install SDL, build it (and there are some trouble for me, because of my project structure). So I don't want to use SDL. **Are there any ways how to play a videofile   with sound synchronously without using SDL?**